# Control error VS WP8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

> Cannot find type System.Windows.Controls.Control in module System.Windows.dll

Hi. I get this error in my WP8.1 App. I don't know what could be. I read all posts from StackOverflow and I didn't find anything. Also, all I get is this error, no line or file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Use this namespace : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls

Comment: where in your project are you using that namepace?